# Real cubed roots of r

Tags: roots

If r is any real-number, then r has a real cube root, which is $\sqrt[3]{r}$. Show that $w$$\sqrt[3]{r}$ and $w^2$$\sqrt[3]{r}$ are also cube roots.

Not really sure how to answer this.  I know that cubes have a real root and a couple imaginary. So I guess the real root times $w$ or $w^2$ would still be real.

EDIT: w = $-1/2$  + $\sqrt{3}i/2$

Comment: In the problem statement, $w$ is a complex number. So the real root times $w$ or $w^2$ is *not* real, but complex.

Comment: I would start by writing $x^3=r$ and solving $x^3-r=0$ for $x$.Other way could be to prove that $(w\sqrt[3]{r})^3=r$

Comment: cub roots of what?

Comment: What is w and w^2.  If w and w^2 are real numbers then $w\sqrt[3]r$ is a cube root of $w^3r$.  And if $w$ is not real then $w\sqrt[3]r$ is only a real cube root of $w^3$ is real.  Do you mean $w$ and $w$ are the complex cube roots of 1  (or -1)?

Answer (score 2):

Well, um, $(w^k\sqrt[3]r)^3 = w^{3k}r = (w^3)r=r$.  I'm assuming you meant $w$ is complex root of $1$?